# SimpleDateFormat: how to correctly format a Date String containing letter T?

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

I have the following `String` that represents a `Date`:

```
2017-01-30T19:00:00+0000
```

I would like to change it to a Date Object using `SimpleDateFormat`.

What is the correct format for this string?

I have read the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API and cant see anything relating to a T?

Comment: Put it in single quotes: `....'T'....`. It's just a literal `T` in the string.

Comment: But really, don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use the classes in `java.time` which are not awful and full of deprecated, broken methods.

Comment: I am still unable how to convert this to a date object? Can you please show with an Answer?

Comment: You have a date string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. See this question: [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String dateString = "2017-01-30T19:00:00+0000";
try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(date);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    //throw exception
}
```